# structure of UDID of iPhone

Tags: iphone

can anyone tell me the structure of UDID of a iphone . I want to use the UDID to identify each user saperately in my app. The UDID seems to be a 40 digit string . In my app i dont want to use such a big ID. Can any one tell me the structure of the UDID so that i can cut short and make out a small unique string from UDID....

Comment: Remember that the UDID identifies a device - not a user. If you use it to identify users, and a user loses their iPhone/iPod or buys an upgrade, they will lose their account because it was tied to the device.

Comment: You can probably just use the first 39 characters and that would be unique enough. YOUR WELCOME. ;-)

Comment: I dont want to do that (probably u might have done that) .I have found a better way. Comments like these deserves no place in stackoverflow..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW12):

> A unique device identifier is a hash value composed from various hardware identifiers such as the device’s serial number.

I wouldn't recommend changing it, as then you aren't guaranteed any uniqueness. There isn't a structure to it such that you can ignore characters; it's a hash. Do you have a good reason for preferring fewer than 40 characters?

Comment: jeff is the serial number unique for an iphone ?. how can i get the serial number of iphone programmatically....?

Comment: post separate question if you want to ask something new.. but first, search for the answer before you ask a question here buddy. a single search will tell you how to get UDID programmatically -  [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]; ... still read the related discussion in different questions regarding UDID so that you don't use it in wrong way...